# Android - Vertically center button at the bottom of a toolbar (like Google Calendar)

Tags: android, toolbar, floating-action-button

I'm trying to recreate something like the Google Calendar event screen with it's edit FAB (see the screenshot below), but I'm not sure how to approach it.

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button) for my FAB

[image]